# What i am doing wrong here?? why any(JSONObject::class.java) showing null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockito

i am testing emitChatMessage function :

```
fun emitChatMessage(chatId: String, sender: String, content: String, messageType: String) {
    val message = JSONObject().apply {
        put("chatId", chatId)
        put("sender", sender)
        put("content", content)
        put("messageType", messageType)
    }

    socketDataSource.emit(CommonFunctionAndVariables.CHAT_KEYS.NEW_MESSAGE, message)
}
```

can't understood do i wrote test right or wron here but getting any(JSONObject::class.java) error here...

```
@Test
fun `test Emit Chat Message`() {
    val chatId = "64393f76ca21bdf658d19bd2"
    val sender = "John"
    val content = "Hello"
    val messageType = "text"

    val capturedMessage = mutableListOf<JSONObject>()
    `when`(socketDataSource.emit(anyString(), any(JSONObject::class.java))).thenAnswer {
        val message = it.arguments[1] as JSONObject
        capturedMessage.add(message)
    }

    repository.emitChatMessage(chatId, sender, content, messageType)
}
```

this is the error:

```
any(JSONObject::class.java) must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: any(JSONObject::class.java) must not be null
    at cc.mekanism.chatconcept.feature_send_message.domain.repository.SocketRepositoryTest.test Emit Chat Message(SocketRepositoryTest.kt:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

when anyone try to emit from socketDataSource like with any string or any json object that should capture the message so i can verify it.

SocketDataSource as you guys asked in comments :

```
package cc.mekanism.chatconcept.feature_send_message.data.remote

    import org.json.JSONObject
    
    interface SocketDataSource {
        fun connect(userId: String, authToken: String)
        fun emit(event: String, data: JSONObject)
        fun on(event: String, listener: (data: JSONObject) -> Unit)
        fun disconnect()
    }
```

Socket Repository Code For Emit Chat Messages:

```
fun emitChatMessage(chatId: String, sender: String, content: String, messageType: String) {
        val message = JSONObject().apply {
            put("chatId", chatId)
            put("sender", sender)
            put("content", content)
            put("messageType", messageType)
        }

        socketDataSource.emit(CommonFunctionAndVariables.CHAT_KEYS.NEW_MESSAGE, message)
    }
```

Comment: Is `JSONObject::class.java` legal Kotlin code? In Java it would simply be `JSONObject.class`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, that's the way to do it in Kotlin (`JSONObject::class` to get a KClass, then `.java` to resolve it to a Java `Class`)

Comment: Can you show how you're setting up the `socketDataSource` mock? It looks like your `when` call is calling the actual method implementation with the return value of `any` (which is always `null`).

Comment: It needs to be a mock, and that mock needs to be injected into repository. How are you creating the mock, and what do you do to inject the dependency?

Comment: Are you using mockito-kotlin ?

Comment: @marcinj yes i am doing in kotlin

Comment: @Jorn let me update socket data source in question

Comment: Ok guys i understood what was the problem , i was using the argument matchers any for json , but instead of that we can just do org.mockito.kotlin.any (or org.mockito.Mockito.any if not using Kotlin extensions) for argument matching.